# Unmatched note sang in a Chord

Tags: voice

In wake me up when september ends, initial chord is G minor and the song starts with a note A..Why is A note used while starting a song on G minor?

Answer (score 3):

For starters, it's in *G major*. The A note is what we call a suspension, as it doesn't actually belong to the chord played under it. However, straight after, the note moves to B, the major third of the chord. So, it sort of makes us feel that he's sung a wrong note that gets corrected immediately afterwards. Kind of tension and release. Made more so as the intro uses only 1 and 5, thus no clues yet as to major or minor.